# How to implement Block cipher modes of operation in java or c++?

Tags: cryptography

I want to implement Electronic codebook (ECB) Cipher-block chaining (CBC) Cipher feedback (CFB) Output feedback (OFB) Counter (CTR) modes either in c++ or in java. But I don't know how and where to start. Can any one please suggest me the steps to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple, let's assume you have a function called `block_cipher_encrypt(plaintext, key)` that takes a single block of plaintext and a key as input and returns a single block of ciphertext.

Now, say you have an array of blocks of plaintext (say `pt[i]` is the ith block of plaintext) and an array `ct` for ciphertext blocks. To do ECB, it would be:

```
for i from 0 to len(pt)-1:  
  ct[i] = block_cipher_encrypt(pt[i], key)
```

For CBC mode, you also need an IV, but it is still pretty simple:

```
ct[0] = block_cipher_encrypt(XOR(pt[0], IV), key)
for i from 1 to len(pt):
  ct[i] = block_cipher_encrypt(XOR(pt[i], ct[i-1]), key)
```

For the other modes, just look at Wikipedia's article on [modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation). They provide nice block diagrams for both encryption and decryption. That is what I did for the pseudocode above.

Comment: Thanks,I have learnt the theory part of different modes,our aim is to encrypt plaintext using an encryption algorithm with a key.My problem is which encrytion algorithm is used and how the key is selected?how the key should be?

Comment: @Nandy, if this is for an actual product that will be used by real life people some day, I suggest you hire an expert consultant. The answer will greatly depend on the project at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The java [Crypto API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html) is a good place to start. It gives a rundown of the The classes that make up the API, as well as how they are used and which classes you would have to extend to implement custom ciphering techniques. Much of what you are trying to do is already available as part of the standard crypto API, so once you get a handle on it, you will only have to customize it for your purposes.

In addition there is the official java [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html) for extending this API with custom encryption techniques which may also be of use.